# How john papa's style works?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, web-frontend

So, I have some code written in john papa style. I tried a lot to understand it but as I am beginner, I didn't get it properly , I didn't get from where code starts running ?. I think I will get some help from here so I am uploading code here and **expecting at least code execution entry point**.

**So here are my some files.**

**1.  index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="fuse">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Fuse - Admin Theme</title>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700italic,700,900,900italic'
              rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
        your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <body md-theme="{{vm.themes.active.name}}" md-theme-watch ng-controller="IndexController as vm"
          class="{{state.current.bodyClass || ''}}">

        <!-- SPLASH SCREEN -->
        <ms-splash-screen id="splash-screen">
            <div class="center">
                <div class="logo">
                    <span>F</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Material Design Spinner -->
                <div class="spinner-wrapper">
                    <div class="spinner">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="gap"></div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / Material Design Spinner -->
            </div>
        </ms-splash-screen>
        <!-- / SPLASH SCREEN -->

        <div id="main" class="animate-slide-up" ui-view="main" layout="column"></div>

        <ms-theme-options></ms-theme-options>

    </body>
</html>
```

**2. index.run.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fuse')
        .run(runBlock);

    /** @ngInject */
    function runBlock($rootScope, $timeout, $state, editableThemes)
    {
        // 3rd Party Dependencies
        editableThemes.default.submitTpl = '<md-button class="md-icon-button" type="submit" aria-label="save"><md-icon md-font-icon="icon-checkbox-marked-circle" class="md-accent-fg md-hue-1"></md-icon></md-button>';
        editableThemes.default.cancelTpl = '<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$form.$cancel()" aria-label="cancel"><md-icon md-font-icon="icon-close-circle" class="icon-cancel"></md-icon></md-button>';

        // Activate loading indicator
        var stateChangeStartEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function ()
        {
            $rootScope.loadingProgress = true;
        });

        // De-activate loading indicator
        var stateChangeSuccessEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function ()
        {
            $timeout(function ()
            {
                $rootScope.loadingProgress = false;
            });
        });

        // Store state in the root scope for easy access
        $rootScope.state = $state;

        // Cleanup
        $rootScope.$on('$destroy', function ()
        {
            stateChangeStartEvent();
            stateChangeSuccessEvent();
        });
    }
})();
```

**3.  index.route.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fuse')
        .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)
    {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard-project');

        // Inject $cookies
        var $cookies;

        angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke([
            '$cookies', function (_$cookies)
            {
                $cookies = _$cookies;
            }
        ]);

        // Get active layout
        var layoutStyle = $cookies.get('layoutStyle') || 'verticalNavigation';

        var layouts = {
            verticalNavigation  : {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/vertical-navigation.html',
                toolbar   : 'app/toolbar/layouts/vertical-navigation/toolbar.html',
                navigation: 'app/navigation/layouts/vertical-navigation/navigation.html'
            },
            verticalNavigationFullwidthToolbar  : {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/vertical-navigation-fullwidth-toolbar.html',
                toolbar   : 'app/toolbar/layouts/vertical-navigation-fullwidth-toolbar/toolbar.html',
                navigation: 'app/navigation/layouts/vertical-navigation/navigation.html'
            },
            verticalNavigationFullwidthToolbar2  : {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/vertical-navigation-fullwidth-toolbar-2.html',
                toolbar   : 'app/toolbar/layouts/vertical-navigation-fullwidth-toolbar-2/toolbar.html',
                navigation: 'app/navigation/layouts/vertical-navigation-fullwidth-toolbar-2/navigation.html'
            },
            horizontalNavigation: {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/horizontal-navigation.html',
                toolbar   : 'app/toolbar/layouts/horizontal-navigation/toolbar.html',
                navigation: 'app/navigation/layouts/horizontal-navigation/navigation.html'
            },
            contentOnly         : {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/content-only.html',
                toolbar   : '',
                navigation: ''
            },
            contentWithToolbar  : {
                main      : 'app/core/layouts/content-with-toolbar.html',
                toolbar   : 'app/toolbar/layouts/content-with-toolbar/toolbar.html',
                navigation: ''
            }
        };
        // END - Layout Style Switcher

        // State definitions
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                abstract: true,
                views   : {
                    'main@'         : {
                        templateUrl: layouts[layoutStyle].main,
                        controller : 'MainController as vm'
                    },
                    'toolbar@app'   : {
                        templateUrl: layouts[layoutStyle].toolbar,
                        controller : 'ToolbarController as vm'
                    },
                    'navigation@app': {
                        templateUrl: layouts[layoutStyle].navigation,
                        controller : 'NavigationController as vm'
                    },
                    'quickPanel@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/quick-panel/quick-panel.html',
                        controller : 'QuickPanelController as vm'
                    }
                }
            });
    }

})();
```

**4.  index.module.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Main module of the Fuse
     */
    angular
        .module('fuse', [

            // Common 3rd Party Dependencies
            'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
            'textAngular',
            'xeditable',

            // Core
            'app.core',

            // Navigation
            'app.navigation',

            // Toolbar
            'app.toolbar',

            // Quick Panel
            'app.quick-panel',

            // Apps
            'app.dashboards',
            'app.calendar',
            'app.e-commerce',
            'app.mail',
            'app.chat',
            'app.file-manager',
            'app.gantt-chart',
            'app.scrumboard',
            'app.todo',
            'app.contacts',
            'app.notes',

            // Pages
            'app.pages',

            // User Interface
            'app.ui',

            // Components
            'app.components'
        ]);
})();
```

**5. index.controller.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fuse')
        .controller('IndexController', IndexController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function IndexController(fuseTheming)
    {
        var vm = this;

        // Data
        vm.themes = fuseTheming.themes;

        //////////
    }
})();
```

Comment: So what do you want ? Something does not work, or you just want an explanation ? Because if you want an explanation, just go to Angular's documentation, `John papa` is a way of writing code, but it does not affect Angular's lifecycle.

Comment: Sir, I don't want explanation but at least some hint about execution so I can proceed further. I didn't understand where from the execution get starts.

Comment: So you don't understand in which order Angular works ? Then you should read the documentation. Is this for a special thing you want to do, or just for personal knowledge ?

Comment: I want to customize it and dissect it just because it is based on angular1 and want to convert it into angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your JS files in your `index.html` file in some way. You could do this as easily as adding script tags manually in your index file. They'd look something like this:

```
<script src="YOUR-FILE-NAME"></script>
```

Your angular app is declared in `index.module.js` and specifies your application's dependencies.

Most of the code you have provided looks right. This answers your question though regarding the application's entry point: `index.html` includes your javascript files which contain your application code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: your answer is correct, but he also needs to include the tag: ng-app="fuse" in a div in index.html. That is the actual bootstrapping of the Angular app in html. Otherwise, the app is not initialized anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @IuliaMihet - The `<html>` element already has an `ng-app` directive on it.

Comment: sorry, didn't look at <html>, I normally bootstrap my apps in the body :-)

Comment: Actually, the part of script tags is added by gulp. and gulp simply add app.js and vendor.js thats it.

Comment: Perfect - I'm glad this helped! Good luck!

Comment: But app.js also have a same code. gulp combined all code in one file. But still I didn't understand the start of execution. actually it is more confusing for me because of having so much modular and big code.

Comment: You haven't included the gulp file so it's hard for me to comment on this. If your gulp file has a task that minifiess/concatenates all your JS files into one, then all you need to do is include this file in your index.html. It will contain everything else.

Comment: I want to customize it and dissect it just because it is based on angular1  and want to convert it into angular2.